# React Material start script NODE_PATH not recognized

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have downloaded following React Material template
[template](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react)

Followed steps from [documentation](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard-react/#/documentation/tutorial)

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-react",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "description": "Material Dashboard React. Coded by Creative Tim",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "build-package-css": "cp src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css dist/material-dashboard-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist"
  },
 
}
```

Getting the following error 
[image]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using Windows. The project was likely ran on unix based computers before (`NODE_PATH=./src` is not a windows way of defining environment variables). You can either fix it by using the Windows syntax `"start": "set NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts start",` (your project will not run on unix machines) or use a cross-env library for defining your environment : https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Resolved the error, however it is exiting from command promt and not opening in browser

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Alright. What you may try is removing `set NODE_PATH=./src` from the package.json (which makes the projet not usable on a unix system), and launch the project by typing `set NODE_PATH="./src" npm start` in your command line.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I had the same issue with the same template and my solution was to configure a file in the project root as specified in this [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports).

I'm using docker and my working directory is in the **/app** directory, so I added this line in my **tsconfig.json** file at the root of my react app folder:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        ...,
        "baseUrl": "/app/src",
}
```